# Why cant I access object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm using react/redux/router and am accessing the id from the url parameter which then i'm finding the associated object with matching id in my redux store. All is well un-till I try and access anything on that object. It just says "object.title" is undefined for instance even though when I console.log() the object all properties are there and it is not undefined.

Im stumped lol. I feel like i'm over looking something here or am maybe not understanding the component life cycle well enough in react.

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../ui/Header'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'  
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Button, Container, TextField, Grid, Typography} from '@material-ui/core'

export default function GifPage() {
  
  const location = useLocation()
  const results = useSelector(state => state.results)
  const id = location.pathname.substring(1);
  const gif = results.find(gif => gif.id === id) 

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(gif)
  },[])

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
        <h1></h1>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item>
          {/* <img src={gif.images.original} alt={gif.title} /> */}
          <Typography>{gif.title}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
  <Typography>{gif && gif.title ? gif.title : null }</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put `debugger;` just before the `return` statement, and run the code, and now in the devtools if you check the value of `const gif`, are you saying it has the title property alright?

My guess is it doesn't, else in `<Typography>{gif.title}</Typography>` you would have no problem.

If my guess is wrong, I apologise.